# Infinite loop in C wont stop for scanf

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I started learning C and i am still at simple programs but with a ton of errors :/
The following code once it catches the wrong input (in the else statement) will continue running and it wont stop for the next scan... why is that happening?

```
const float inch_to_cm = 2.54;

int main()
{
    bool run = true;
    float usr_input;
    while(run){
        printf("Please enter the inches: ");
        if (scanf("%f", &usr_input) == 1){
            printf("Result: %4.2f \n", inch_to_cm*usr_input);
            run = false;
        }
        else{
            printf("I asked for a number!\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your wrong input ?

Comment: If you just started learning C, you probably [should not be posting on this website](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/596781). Once you're ready to post meaningful contributions to Stack Overflow, you will no longer "just have started learning C".

Comment: You need   consume an invalid input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are entering anything else than a numerical value then it will not read by `scanf` and live there for infinite time causing infinite loop. You must have to flush the input buffer.  Place this after the `else` statement:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```